# MultipartException when upload file with angular/spring

Tags: angular, spring-boot

when i try to upload a file with angular/spring i got an exception : org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request , but when i try it with postman it work

my code : angular

upload.service.ts :

```
public save(file: File) {
    this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    const formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', file);
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "upload", formdata, { headers: 
    this.headers }).map(resp => resp.json());

}
```

upload component :

```
  currentFileUpload: File;

  constructor(private uploadService: UploadService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  selectFile(event) {
    this.currentFileUpload = event.target.files[0];
  }

  uploadFile() {
    this.uploadService.save(this.currentFileUpload).subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
    },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

html code :

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" (change)="selectFile($event)" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">choisissez un fichier (*pdf, *csv ,*docs)</label>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="uploadFile()">Upload</button>
</div>
```

code backend :

```
@PostMapping("/api/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    String name = file.getOriginalFilename();
     if (!file.isEmpty()) {
         try {
             byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
             BufferedOutputStream stream =
                     new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("src/upload/"+name)));
             stream.write(bytes);
             stream.close();
             return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
         } catch (Exception e) {
             return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
         }
     } else {
         return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
     }

}
```

when i try it with postman : 
[image]

Spring Exception : 
[image]

Comment: set Content-Type dynamically  using event.target.files[0].type instead of hard code

Comment: how can i do it ?

Comment: i already send the request without headers but the problem still the same !

Comment: Could you please compare your headers with the ones Postman sending. Also if you can use Fiddler (or a similar tool) it can help debug this kind of situations.